# How do i find the nearest value and place it in a third column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

this may sound dull to you experts but i have no expertise whatsoever in Excel and am hoping you can help me..

I have the following:

COLUMN A (A1:A100) FULL OF VALUES

COLUMN B (B1:B100) EMPTY

And COLUMN C (C1:C30) FULL OF VALUES

I am trying to do the following:

- To find the nearest value (numerical value not position wise) to A1 from within C1:C30 and then copy that nearest value (a value coming from C1:C30 that is nearest to A1)into B1 and so forth until B100..
- For Example:
- if A1=6 and C1:C3=1,2,5;
- The nearest numerical value to A1 would be 5
- 5 would be placed in B1

----- I am sorry if i didn't explain it clearly but please let me know if so..

thanks in advance

Comment: An example would be good. When you say "Values" are those numbers? When you say "Nearest" do you mean positionally or as a value?

Comment: barry thank you for your come in into this.. i have edited the post as you requested.. i intend to find the nearest number from within C1:C30 that is the nearest number to A1 and so on.. for example, if A1=6 and C1:C3=1,2,5; The nearest numerical value would be 5 and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In B1 put this formula:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$100,MATCH(MIN(ABS($A$1:$A$100-C1)),ABS($A$1:$A$100-C1),0),)
```

and be sure to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> from the formula bar when you have pasted it otherwise you will get N/A.

Then drag this formula down. This will find the closest value to cell C1 looking up the value in the range A1:A100.

**The Reverse**

Apparently you are after the reverse:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$30,MATCH(MIN(ABS($C$1:$C$30-A1)),ABS($C$1:$C$30-A1),0),)
```

This will find the closest value to cell A1 looking up the values in C1:C30.

Comment: Nice Answer......although I think that mad is looking for A1 in col C not C1 in col A but obviously you can amend accordingly.......

Comment: Good point, must have misread it.

Comment: thanks berry & dan! i have managed to trial around with it using the reverse.. it works perfectly for the A1!.. but for the rest it seems to compare A values with the corresponding C values and above without including the first C values, in other words the list of C1:C30 becomes C2:C31 then C3:C32 when A1 becomes A2 and A3!.. any ways around that?

Comment: i need the A values compared with C1:C30 all the time! i am sorry im making it harder but i have no other choice but to seek for your help ;(

Comment: If you have pasted the formula as I have given then the C values will not update because they are surrounded with $. Having the dollar signs means that it is an absolute reference http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/r/g/absolute_cell_r.htm

Comment: WoW! i'v got it solved now.. thanks alot.. you saved me from going one by one across 100 columns now!

Comment: p.s. is there a way to implement that across 100 columns all at once or its very much to ask from excel?

Comment: Not sure what you mean